# Procurar elemento em um array usando array.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma grid onde em cada linha há um botão de deletar o dado correspondente.
Essa grid é alimentada por um json porém não há id. Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para deletar o objeto selecionado, sendo que a grid está sendo alimentada por um ng-repeat e para deletar um dado eu tenho que pegar o click, remover o item do array e dar um post com todos os dados para o server de volta.

Segue o que eu estou tentando fazer (e não está dando certo)

```
ng.remover = function(liberados){
    var ind;
    allow.url.forEach(function (lib, i){
        if(liberados == lib){
            ind = i;
        }
    });
    allow.url.splice(1,ind);
    var allowCopied = angular.copy(allow);      
    allowCopied.name = allowCopied.url;

    ng.tudo.allowedSitesList.push( allowCopied );
    $http({method: "POST", url: "http://localhost:0000/in", data: ng.tudo})
        .then(function (dados) {});     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi o que você quis fazer na sua função, mas caso queira comparar se contem um item em um foreach em angular, tente fazer assim:

```
$scope.allow = [{"url":"google.com"}, {"url":"uol.com"}, {"url":"globo.com"}, {"url":"msn.com"}];

$scope.denied = [];

$scope.remove = function(urlLiberada){
    //chama o foreach do angular
    angular.forEach($scope.allow, function (item,index){
        //verifica se contem
        if(item.url.indexOf(urlLiberada) != -1){
            //adiciona o item a lista denied
            $scope.denied.push(item);   
            //remove da lista allow
            $scope.allow.splice(index);                  
        }
    });
}

//testando a funçao removendo a url msn.com
$scope.remove("msn.com")
```